# how do i make a random number in python using intervals of 10

Tags: python, random

I am currently using random.randint to generate random numbers, but I  would like that it  will print out numbers in the intervals  of 10

eg. 10, 20, 30,  40, 50...

how would I do this?

I have tried: random.randint()

how do I make it generate in multiples of 10 like this?

Answer (score 1):

Just do `random.randint(1, 10) * 10` should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the random.randrange method.

With something like randrange(0, 100, 10) you can generate random multiples of 10 between 0 and 100.